# Credential pass through for Databricks Sql

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, azure-data-lake-gen2

We have so far used Databricks for Data Engineering and Data Science purposes but recently have started exploring the new Databricks Sql analytics as we have a lot of SQL Analysts who also want to join the bandwagon (for some use cases).

However, the big stumbling block I have noticed is that a SQL endpoint always needs a Service Principal for Azure Data Lake Gen2 access. There is no option to just use “credential pass through “ without using a SPN.

I have tried looking up the limitations (known issues)page as well as all existing documentation but have not come across anything regarding this.

Can’t we just use a High Concurency cluster with credential pass through for data lake gen 2 (or a single user standard cluster with credential pass through) without using any spn at all (just like we do for data engineering and data science workloads)? Or at least a timeline?

This really is important in regards to fine grained security requirements in organizations for accessing Production data .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, this is **currently not supported**.

Only ways available are as below.

> [image]

I can see similar requests already shared as ideas [here](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/6c0e3c88-f024-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0da0) and [here](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/f8c756ef-ef24-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0da0). You can post one too or reach support team for an official response.